# what is triggered in click-and-drag date histogram event in kibana

Tags: javascript, jquery, kibana

I have a kibana dashboard embeded in a webpage and would like to dynamically find the start date/time and end date/time of my kibana dashboards when the time range is narrowed by a user clicking and dragging the time range.

I plan on accomplishing this by extracting the json request that is sent after this event is triggered which conveniently stores the start and end data, but I don't know what event is exactly triggered and when exactly it is appropriate to extract it.
I would also be comfortable with extracting the data whenever the request is changed even though this admittedly a less direct route.

**How can I recognize when the date histogram range has been narrowed by a click-and-drag?**

Answer (score 0):

If you have embedded the dashboard in a webpage, So if user changes the time range every other parameter would be dynamically changed in the dashboard.

I don't think there is a need for you to recognize date histogram range.

Comment: I need to be able to print the start and end range as soon as it is updated.